# React: array value are undefined in map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, object

I'm making react app that renders all products from firebase. I'm getting object data and replacing image array with new array with correct url link. After that I set state with array of objects. Everything goes well until I need to map that array of objects and get first image from images array from object. I can access all data from object, also I can get **images** array, but when I pointed to exact value **(images[0])** I get *undefined*

my code

```
export default class List extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loaded: false,
            productsArr: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            loaded: true
        })
        db.collection('products').get().then((list) => {
            let productsArr = []
            list.forEach((doc) => {
                let obj = doc.data();
                let imgArr =[];
                obj.images.forEach((img) => {
                    storageRef.child(`images/${img}`)
                    .getDownloadURL()
                    .then(url =>{
                        imgArr.push(url)
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log('Getting image url ERROR', err)
                    })
                })
                const newObj = Object.assign(obj, {images: imgArr})
                productsArr.push(newObj)
            })
            this.setState({
                productsArr,
            })
        })
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Header />
                {this.state.loaded ? <Loading /> : null}
                <div>
                    {this.state.productsArr.map((product, i) => {
                        let arr = product.images
                        console.log(arr)
                        return (
                            <div key={i}>
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <img src={product.images[0]}
                                            alt={product.category} 
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

how object looks:

```
{
   category: "wooden",
   color: "black",
   height: "13",
   id: "103A220",
   images: ["https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/remini…=media&token=8668-deeac8dd21e0"],
   price: "4",
   productName: "Wood",
   warehouse: true,
   width: "14"
}
```

Comment: Can you see the product object from that console.log? console.log(arr)

Comment: that log is only for testing purpose, but wit arr variable I can see images array with value. If I log _product_ then I can see product object

Comment: Try this one. `this.state && this.state.productsArr && this.state.productsArr.map(` Because I tried the same thing you have implemented. Rendring part is totally fine. The only problem that can be occurred is productArr is not fully loaded in the reder section.

Comment: I tried and got same result  _undefined_

Comment: You have to use the render after checking this.state.productsArr. Just put a if statement `if(this.state.productsArr){render(){your mapping code}} else {render(){return(<div></div>)}}`

Comment: I'm not sure where I should to put if statement, because if I put before `render()` I will get an error

Comment: After a second though, I think the problem comes from this promise: `getDownloadURL()`. `obj.images.forEach` ends before any of the `getDownloadURL()` promises resolve, and `list.forEach()` as well. You end up adding  empty image array to the state. Try adding a `console.log` right before the `setState` to see

Comment: I am really sorry. If statement should place after the render and before the return. In else part you can return an empty div.

Comment: I added `console.log(productsArr)`, and logged out to console full array with all information I need as should be.

Comment: It doesn't work too, same result, got all information except images

Comment: Hmm, that can be because as you do `array.push`, the array ref is still the same and you browser console is able to see them even if they are updated afterwards. Not sure, but it's a possibility. When you log them in the render method, are there still all the informations you need ?

Comment: For testing purpose I added `console.log()` in `componentDidMount()` in first line, next added in `componentDidMound()` in `db.collection...` before `this.setState()` and then in `render()`. And cosole shows me by this order: render first time with empty `productsArr`, then logged `componentDidMount()` first log, then render again empty `productsArr` , then logged out `db.collection...` log with data `productsArr` and then render `productsArr` with full data

Answer (score 0):

My guess: calls to `getDownloadURL()` doesn't resolve before all the `foreach`s are  done. It result in updating the state with objects mostly containing empty `images` arrays.

To ensure all the async flow is performed before `setState` you got to wait for the promises to resolve.

Try replacing your `componentDidUpdate()` with the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
  db.collection("products")
    .get()
    .then((list) =>
      list.map((doc) => {
        // Get object
        const obj = doc.data();

        // Get all the images urls
        // This returns an array of promises
        const urlsPromises = obj.images.map((img) => {
          return storageRef.child(`images/${img}`).getDownloadURL();
        });

        // Pass the array of promises to Promise.all
        // and receive an array of urls that you assign to the obj.images key
        return Promise.all(urlsPromises)
          .then((urls) => Object.assign(obj, { images: urls }))
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Getting image url ERROR", err);
            // In case of error, keep the obj object as it is
            // Handle this as you which, this is an exemple
            return obj;
          });
      })
    )
    // Wait for the array of promises generated in the previous then
    .then(Promise.all)
    // Handle the array of altered obj
    .then((productArr) => this.setState({ loaded: true, productArr }))
    // Handle error as you like
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

And update this condition in your `render()` method:

```
{this.state.loaded ? null : <Loading />}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate ? Like give some details about the error ?

Comment: it just type error: TypeError: list.map is not a function
    at list.js:23

Comment: `list` is not an array ?

Comment: Your entity might be a `Map`, then just perform a `Array.from(list.entries()).map(.... )` to convert it to an array and chain a map.

Comment: now getting error: TypeError: list.entries is not a function

Comment: Could you explain what the `list` object is ? Because I'm trying to help you but it feels like you want me to guess everything